# GET specific item from table on click in Django MVT

Tags: python, django, django-views, arguments, jinja2

I have a table of products being displayed in my template using Jinja loop.

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block css %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href= "{% static 'css\store.css' %}" >
{% endblock %}

{%block content%}
{% load static %}
<div class="secondnav">
  <a class="nav-item" href="construction"> Figures </a>
  <a class="nav-item" href="construction"> Manga </a>
  <a class="nav-item" href="construction"> Clothes </a>
</div>
{% for product in products %}
<div class="container2">
  <div href="item" class= 'product-item'>
    <div class= 'image-cont'>
      {# Pass the id of the product to the item view when the user clicks on the product #}
      <a href="{% url 'item' product.id %}"><img class='product-image'src = '{{product.product_picture.url}}' alt="" ></a>
    </div>
    {% if product.offer != 0 %}
    <div class= 'offer-banner' >
      {# Pass the id of the product to the item view when the user clicks on the offer banner #}
      <a href="{% url 'item' product.id %}">Special Offer</a>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    </div>
      <div href="item" class="product-content">
        <div href="item" class="product-title">
          {# Pass the id of the product to the item view when the user clicks on the product title #}
          <a href="{% url 'item' product.id %}" >{{product.name}}</a> 
        </div> 
        <div class="product-price">
          {# Pass the id of the product to the item view when the user clicks on the product price #}
          <a href="{% url 'item' product.id %}" >${{product.price}}</a> 
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="product-desc">
          {# Pass the id of the product to the item view when the user clicks on the product description #}
          <a href="{% url 'item' product.id %}" >{{product.desc}}</a> 
        </div> 
        <br>
        <div class="product-userpfp">
          {# Pass the id of the product to the item view when the user clicks on the user's profile picture #}
          <a href="{% url 'item' product.id %}" ><img src='{{product.userpfp.url}}'></a> 
        </div> 
        <br>
        <div class="product-poster-name">
          {# Pass the id of the product to the item view when the user clicks on the user's name #}
          <a href="{% url 'item' product.id %}" >{{product.username}}</a>
        </div>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I want to click on one instance shown in the loop and get the id of that instance into my 'item' view. My 'item' view delivers a page of just the singular item. By typing it in the url in the browser it delivers the correct page with context. Here is the view

```py
def store(request):
  products = Product.objects.all()
  return render(request, 'store.html', {'products': products}) ;

def item(request, item_id):
  # Get the item with the given id
  item = Product.objects.get(id=item_id)
  return render(request, "item.html", {"item": item })
```

and here is the app urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "login"

urlpatterns = [
  path("", views.home, name='home'),
  path("login", views.login, name="login"),
  path("register", views.register, name="register"),
  path("profile", views.profile, name="profile"),
  path("logout", views.logout, name="logout"),
  path("store/", views.store, name="store"),
  path("commissions", views.commissions, name="commissions"),
  path("port", views.port, name="port"),
  path("item/<int:item_id>", views.item, name="item"),
  path("construction", views.construction, name="construction"),

]
```

I now receive an error when I click to open the store

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: Reverse for 'item' not found. 'item' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

I looked on lots of StackOverflow and came to the 'dupe link' for this error. Someone there said:

> The arguments part is typically an object from your models. Remember
> to add it to your context in the view. Otherwise a reference to the
> object in the template will be empty and therefore not match a url
> with an object_id.

I think this may be the problem but Im not sure. Someone else said:

> Watch out for different arguments passing between reverse() and
> redirect() for example: `url(r"^some_app/(?P<some_id>\d+)/$", some_view_function, name="some_view")` will work with:
> `reverse("some_view", kwargs={"some_id": my_id})` and:
> `redirect("some_view", some_id=my_id)` but not with:
> `reverse("some_view", some_id=my_id)` and: `redirect("some_view", kwargs={"some_id": my_id})`

Since it is a `NoReverseMatch` maybe I have to use `reverse` here? But Im not sure how I would fit that in to my current views.

Comment: Since you defined `app_name = "login"` in your **urls.py**, you have to refer to that namespace in your views and templates when using the name for that url.  In your templates it would be `<a href="{% url 'login:item' product.id %}" >`, for example.  You **don't** have any redirects in your views currently that I can see, but *if you did* it would look something like `return redirect('login:item')`.